# Using Protocol Buffers in Highly Regulated Environment (Medical)

Tags: protocol-buffers, medical

I'm currently in the process of overhauling the communications protocol used on a medical device.  After some investigation, using something like Protocol Buffers fits the bill really well due to its flexibility and small packet footprint.  While I am sure that the protocol is more reliable than what we are using currently (a custom serial protocol developed in-house), there is some concern that it might not be appropriate for use in medical applications since it has not been formally validated.  If I can show that another highly regulated company has used it (medical/aerospace/etc...) it would truly go a long way.  Are there any examples of Protocol Buffers, or something similar, being used in a highly regulated environment?

Note: The protocol would be used to communicate serially between a PC and a microprocessor on a separate board.

Comment: Consider that there is a distinction between the protocol buffer specification (which describes how to define a buffer, and how to convert to and from the wire format), and the code that implements it. You are probably more interested in validation of the code, which is very different depending on the language.

Comment: Yes, presumably the thing you want to "validate" is not the spec but a specific implementation. Which language will you be using protobufs in? FWIW, Google's official implementation (of which I'm the primary author, though I've since left the company) has been reviewed by Google's security team. Google is not highly regulated, but they have the best defensive security team on the planet, and I'd trust them over any regulator. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on DICOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) protocol, it is very commonly used on medical devices (especially for image transfer) and in communication between them.